# Ошибка 429 Too Many Requests discord.py clear command

Tags: discord.py, clear

Делаю дискорд бота и столкнулся с проблемой, в дискорде при удалении сообщений есть лимит, 5 сообщений за раз, мне нужно чтобы он вы полнял все 100 сообщений а не только 5
код:

```
async def clear(ctx, amount:str, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))
        await ctx.send(f"Успешно очищено {int(amount)} сообщений")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount), check=lambda m: m.author == member)
        await ctx.send(f"Успешно очищено {int(amount)} сообщений от {member}")
```

error:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): You are being rate limited.
```

Comment: Делай задержку между запросами

Comment: как? я не шарю...

Comment: Раз уж метод асинхронный, то задержку можно устроить при помощи [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

Comment: как? сразу код я не понимаю тебя какой asyncio как его использовать